# centering a navbar when screen resizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

I am trying to centre my navbar, after my screen resizes to a smaller size.  I have made sure that my class containing my navigation: `.menu` has the following

```
display: 
inline-block; 
margin: 0px auto;
```

It still doesn't centre...

However, my logo contained in the div above, has the same properties and it is able to centre when the screen resizes.

My menu HTML

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
        <span class="fa fa-bars"> </span>
    </button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar-brand logo-top"> </a>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-offcanvas sidebar-nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href=“#A" data-section=“A”>A</a></li>
        <li><a href=“#B" data-section=“B”>B</a></li>
        <li><a href=“#C" data-section=“C”>C</a></li>
        <li><a href=“#D" data-section=“D”>D</a></li>
        <li><a href=“#E" data-section=“E”>E</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Can anybody give me some insight?

Comment: please make a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Give Us the code from the parent to the last child of this navbar..

Comment: <nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
<span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar-brand logo-top"></a>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-offcanvas sidebar-nav" role="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="active"><a href=“#A" data-section=“A”>A</a></li>
<li><a href=“#B" data-section=“B”>B</a></li>
<li><a href=“#C" data-section=“C”>C</a></li>
<li><a href=“#D" data-section=“D”>D</a></li>
<li><a href=“#E" data-section=“E”>E</a></li></ul>
</div>
</nav>

Comment: I think my nesting is ok... I can send you the code for the relevant classes to if that will help.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block;` needs `text-align: center;` on the parent element for it to center like you're thinking because it's an inline element.

Instead, use `display: block; margin: 0px auto;`. You'll also need to set the width if it's not all the way across.

[Examples](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/52pw0d45/)

Comment: Thanks so much DACrosby, it didnt centre either... I am gonna have another look at the code and make sure there is not some float attached to one of the the classes in my css that prevents it from centering.. When I inspect element, nothing like that jumps out to me..

Comment: What's the menu doing now? Can you send a link to your website, or better yet create a jsFiddle that replicates the issue? [Here's a starting point.](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/szz0zjqk/).

Comment: I will figure out shortly how to to do jsFiddle in order for you to see it... the website is www.gothrive.io   When you change the screen size to anything below 1200px and above 768px you will notice that the menu covers the top-logo. This is because I recently made a change to the website by adding a section "the Thrive process". My current solution is to try have the logo move above the menu when the screen resizes. Thanks for you insights in advance.

Comment: Your logo is `display: block` with a width set, so add the auto margin to center it: `.logo-top { margin: 25px auto 0; }`. It still overlaps your nav bar because the nav is floated so remove the float on `.nav-sidebar`. Then your logo is below the nav, if you want to the best fix is to simply put it before the nav in your HTML instead of after.